# wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ebs, kubernetes-pvc

I am trying to deploy [mongodb](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb) to my kubernetes cluster. It automatically creates a pvc and pv based on the storage class name i specify. However the pod is stuck on `ContainerCreating` because of the following error:

> MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-f88bdca6-7794-455a-872f-8230f1ce295d" : mount failed: exit status 32 Mounting command: systemd-run Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03 --scope -- mount -t xfs -o debug,defaults /dev/xvdbq /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03 Output: Running scope as unit run-4113.scope. mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

I'm not sure what to do as this is pretty consistant no matter how many times i uninstall and resinstall the helm chart.

**kubectl version**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.4", GitCommit:"e87da0bd6e03ec3fea7933c4b5263d151aafd07c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-02-18T16:12:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19+", GitVersion:"v1.19.6-eks-49a6c0", GitCommit:"49a6c0bf091506e7bafcdb1b142351b69363355a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-23T22:10:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**storage class**

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: mongodbstorage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  fsType: xfs
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

**kubectl describe pod mongodb-prod-0 -n mongodb**

```
Name:           mongodb-prod-0
Namespace:      mongodb
Priority:       0
Node:           ip-10-0-4-244.us-east-2.compute.internal/10.0.4.244
Start Time:     Sat, 24 Apr 2021 20:03:06 +0100
Labels:         app.kubernetes.io/component=mongodb
                app.kubernetes.io/instance=mongodb-prod
                app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                app.kubernetes.io/name=mongodb
                controller-revision-hash=mongodb-prod-58c557d4fc
                helm.sh/chart=mongodb-10.12.5
                statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=mongodb-prod-0
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/mongodb-prod
Containers:
  mongodb:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.4.5-debian-10-r0
    Image ID:      
    Port:          27017/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Command:
      /scripts/setup.sh
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       exec [mongo --disableImplicitSessions --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:      exec [bash -ec mongo --disableImplicitSessions $TLS_OPTIONS --eval 'db.hello().isWritablePrimary || db.hello().secondary' | grep -q 'true'
] delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:
      BITNAMI_DEBUG:                    false
      MY_POD_NAME:                      mongodb-prod-0 (v1:metadata.name)
      MY_POD_NAMESPACE:                 mongodb (v1:metadata.namespace)
      K8S_SERVICE_NAME:                 mongodb-prod-headless
      MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_HOST:     mongodb-prod-0.$(K8S_SERVICE_NAME).$(MY_POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
      MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME:         rs0
      MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD:            <set to the key 'mongodb-root-password' in secret 'mongodb-prod'>    Optional: false
      MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY:          <set to the key 'mongodb-replica-set-key' in secret 'mongodb-prod'>  Optional: false
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD:             no
      MONGODB_SYSTEM_LOG_VERBOSITY:     0
      MONGODB_DISABLE_SYSTEM_LOG:       no
      MONGODB_DISABLE_JAVASCRIPT:       no
      MONGODB_ENABLE_IPV6:              no
      MONGODB_ENABLE_DIRECTORY_PER_DB:  no
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/mongodb from datadir (rw)
      /scripts/setup.sh from scripts (rw,path="setup.sh")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from mongodb-prod-token-4kjjm (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  datadir:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  datadir-mongodb-prod-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  scripts:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      mongodb-prod-scripts
    Optional:  false
  mongodb-prod-token-4kjjm:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  mongodb-prod-token-4kjjm
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  geeiq/node-type=ops
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age   From                     Message
  ----     ------                  ----  ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled               18m   default-scheduler        Successfully assigned mongodb/mongodb-prod-0 to ip-10-0-4-244.us-east-2.compute.internal
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  18m   attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-f88bdca6-7794-455a-872f-8230f1ce295d"
  Warning  FailedMount             18m   kubelet                  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-f88bdca6-7794-455a-872f-8230f1ce295d" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03 --scope -- mount -t xfs -o debug,defaults /dev/xvdbq /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03
Output: Running scope as unit run-4113.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
  Warning  FailedMount  18m  kubelet  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-f88bdca6-7794-455a-872f-8230f1ce295d" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03 --scope -- mount -t xfs -o debug,defaults /dev/xvdbq /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03
Output: Running scope as unit run-4182.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
  Warning  FailedMount  18m  kubelet  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-f88bdca6-7794-455a-872f-8230f1ce295d" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03 --scope -- mount -t xfs -o debug,defaults /dev/xvdbq /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03
Output: Running scope as unit run-4256.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
  Warning  FailedMount  18m  kubelet  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-f88bdca6-7794-455a-872f-8230f1ce295d" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03 --scope -- mount -t xfs -o debug,defaults /dev/xvdbq /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03
Output: Running scope as unit run-4297.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
  Warning  FailedMount  18m  kubelet  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-f88bdca6-7794-455a-872f-8230f1ce295d" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03 --scope -- mount -t xfs -o debug,defaults /dev/xvdbq /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03
Output: Running scope as unit run-4458.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
  Warning  FailedMount  18m  kubelet  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-f88bdca6-7794-455a-872f-8230f1ce295d" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03 --scope -- mount -t xfs -o debug,defaults /dev/xvdbq /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03
Output: Running scope as unit run-4562.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
  Warning  FailedMount  17m  kubelet  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-f88bdca6-7794-455a-872f-8230f1ce295d" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03 --scope -- mount -t xfs -o debug,defaults /dev/xvdbq /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03
Output: Running scope as unit run-4835.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
  Warning  FailedMount  17m  kubelet  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-f88bdca6-7794-455a-872f-8230f1ce295d" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03 --scope -- mount -t xfs -o debug,defaults /dev/xvdbq /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03
Output: Running scope as unit run-5281.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-087b3e95d1aa21e03: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
  Warning  FailedMount  5m30s (x2 over 16m)  kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[datadir], unattached volumes=[scripts mongodb-prod-token-4kjjm datadir]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  3m12s (x3 over 10m)  kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[datadir], unattached volumes=[datadir scripts mongodb-prod-token-4kjjm]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  56s (x11 over 16m)   kubelet  (combined from similar events): Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[datadir], unattached volumes=[datadir scripts mongodb-prod-token-4kjjm]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

**kubectl get pods,svc,pvc,pv -o wide --namespace mongodb**

```
NAME                         READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE                                       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/mongodb-prod-0           0/1     ContainerCreating   0          20m   <none>       ip-10-0-4-244.us-east-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
pod/mongodb-prod-arbiter-0   1/1     Running             5          20m   10.0.4.132   ip-10-0-4-244.us-east-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>

NAME                                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE   SELECTOR
service/mongodb-prod-0-external         NodePort    172.20.91.18    <none>        27017:30001/TCP   20m   app.kubernetes.io/component=mongodb,app.kubernetes.io/instance=mongodb-prod,app.kubernetes.io/name=mongodb,statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=mongodb-prod-0
service/mongodb-prod-1-external         NodePort    172.20.202.43   <none>        27017:30002/TCP   20m   app.kubernetes.io/component=mongodb,app.kubernetes.io/instance=mongodb-prod,app.kubernetes.io/name=mongodb,statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=mongodb-prod-1
service/mongodb-prod-arbiter-headless   ClusterIP   None            <none>        27017/TCP         20m   app.kubernetes.io/component=arbiter,app.kubernetes.io/instance=mongodb-prod,app.kubernetes.io/name=mongodb
service/mongodb-prod-headless           ClusterIP   None            <none>        27017/TCP         20m   app.kubernetes.io/component=mongodb,app.kubernetes.io/instance=mongodb-prod,app.kubernetes.io/name=mongodb

NAME                                           STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS     AGE   VOLUMEMODE
persistentvolumeclaim/datadir-mongodb-prod-0   Bound    pvc-f88bdca6-7794-455a-872f-8230f1ce295d   100Gi      RWO            mongodbstorage   20m   Filesystem

NAME                                                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                            STORAGECLASS     REASON   AGE   VOLUMEMODE
persistentvolume/pvc-f88bdca6-7794-455a-872f-8230f1ce295d   100Gi      RWO            Retain           Bound    mongodb/datadir-mongodb-prod-0   mongodbstorage            20m   Filesystem
```

Update:

**kubectl describe pv pvc-30f3ca78-134b-4b4d-bac9-385a71a6f7e0**

```
Name:              pvc-30f3ca78-134b-4b4d-bac9-385a71a6f7e0
Labels:            failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-2
                   failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-2c
Annotations:       kubernetes.io/createdby: aws-ebs-dynamic-provisioner
                   pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
                   pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:      mongodbstorage
Status:            Bound
Claim:             mongodb/datadir-mongodb-prod-0
Reclaim Policy:    Retain
Access Modes:      RWO
VolumeMode:        Filesystem
Capacity:          100Gi
Node Affinity:     
  Required Terms:  
    Term 0:        failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone in [us-east-2c]
                   failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region in [us-east-2]
Message:           
Source:
    Type:       AWSElasticBlockStore (a Persistent Disk resource in AWS)
    VolumeID:   aws://us-east-2c/vol-08aebae8e0d675c4d
    FSType:     xfs
    Partition:  0
    ReadOnly:   false
Events:         <none>
```

Comment: For what reason do you create a custom storageClass rather than using the default?

Comment: @Jones Right, mongodb documentation strongly suggests using xfs file system, the default storage class is not xfs. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#kernel-and-file-systems

Comment: Secondaly i needed to change the volumeBindingMode to `WaitForFirstConsumer` because when you apply a nodeSelector there is a chance that the pod the node is running on and the pvc region is not the same. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#volume-binding-mode My understanding of this section of the documentation `PersistentVolumes will be selected or provisioned conforming to the topology that is specified by the Pod's scheduling constraints` helps prevent this mismatch.In my case it did, both the pvc and pod are on the same region after applying this

Comment: But the PV is not formatted with XFS just because you write XFS in the storage class, have you created a custom volume provisioner that formates the volumes in this format as well?

Comment: @Jones So youre saying if i set the fsType to XFS it does not format the volume automatically to XFS. So how do i determine what the fsType of the PV is so that i can check that? `custom volume provisioner` I don't know what this is, can you provide a link to some documentation?

Comment: Please check the question, i have updated it to describe the pv and it suggests its of  `FSType:     xfs`. Please note the pv id of this latest command may have a different uuid than original outputs because i have uninstalled and reinstalled this helm chart (provisioning a new pv).

What makes you think it is not XFS and do you have a way of determining if it is or not?

Comment: See your error message: `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock`

Comment: @Jonas Yes it was very ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what the problem was, once i removed the mount options from the storage class and recreated it, it mounted properly.

```
mountOptions:
 - debug
```

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: mongodbstorage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  fsType: xfs
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Comment: I seem to have the same problem with a `mountOptions` set to `uid=100`, which is what their documentation suggests (deploying a Neo4j database to AWS EKS). Did you find a reason for this issue, or did you just remove the `mountOption` field and called it a day?

Comment: @Nils I removed the mountOptions and called it a day